# Click event for Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

Is there a click event/property for the Report Viewer which can return to me what they are clicking on?

The report designer is limited to:

1. Go to Report
2. Go to bookmark
3. Go to url

My report has a field with a file name, I would like to write into my Double Click Event to open the containing folder on DoubleClick.

I dont need help with the code for opening the folder, just on getting what is being doubleclicked on so I can open the correct folder.  Something like

```
private void rptvReport_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(rptvReport.**CURRENTITEM**.text);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the `sender`?

Comment: Wish it was that easy.  Actually I cannot even seem to get the double click event to fire at all.  I changed the Messagebox to just show a "Hello World" and I double click all over the report and no event fires

Comment: Have you tried using a link with file scheme? ie, file://somefolder/somefile.txt. Never tried it but worth a shot if this is a desktop app.

Comment: Yea I am trying to avoid having to do that.  Seems messy.  I think I'm going to have to use a different control and just use the report for printing

Comment: @Cade that is more messy than building the report twice?

Comment: I will probably utilize another method of reporting (Data Grid View or something) than the report tool.  Doing your solution will only link me to the file, but I need more code in their to parse it.  These aren't standard files that can be opened, I need to parse them and do other things to display them properly.

Comment: I'm also toying with the possibility of pre-parsing the information and using a Sub Report to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your report set the textbox action to "go to Url" and the expression for the url set it to:

```
="http://someaction?rowid="+Trim(Str(Fields!SomeIdField.Value))
```

Then in your form use the "Hyperlink" event of the report viewer control:

```
uxReportViewer.Hyperlink += uxReportViewer_Hyperlink;
```

And in the eventhandler:

```
  void uxReportViewer_Hyperlink(object sender, HyperlinkEventArgs e)
  {
     Uri link = new Uri(e.Hyperlink);

     if (link.Authority == "someaction")
     {
        e.Cancel = true; //Cancel the event to avoid opening the browser
        char[] sep=new char[] {'='};
        var param=link.Query.Split(sep);
        string rowId=param[1];
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked on Id: "+rowId.ToString());
     }
  }
```

You can extend this for different actions and more than one parameter

Comment: Hello, Can we use this in webforms?